# Loading and resizing photos using fresco library

Tags: android, fresco

I want to make multiply loading of photos in each cardView at my news feed, like at facebook application.

I found fresco library, but I don't have an algorithm to doing such loading and resizing.

Help me please.

Comment: try to enhance you question by adding the source code regarding your issue

Answer (score 0):

First you need to simply add the following line to the dependencies section of your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.12.0'
```

You use below links for resize:

http://frescolib.org/docs/resizing-rotating.html

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Fresco-Library

Once check for [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) as well

Comment: Thanks! SimpleView is the most well described in documentation. How about more than one pictures in one view? Should I have to create own custom view and write all logic (resizing) in it ?